# Show Captcha from webbrowser in c#

Tags: c#

So I am trying to set up a tool that auto creates accounts but users need to complete captcha codes to verify they are human, I want to get what ever the captcha code image is and show it to the users, I know the elements ID but how would I get a component (or what component would I use) so it only shows that part of the webbroswer ?

My code...

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recaptcha_challenge_image")
```

But after that I am not sure what I would do ? I tried something like...

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recaptcha_challenge_image") = pictureBox1.BackgroundImage;
```

I am not quite sure what to do the site I am trying to get the captcha code from is https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/liquid/reg/account/create-account!input.action

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in the *DocumentCompleted* event to make sure the document has loaded:

```cs
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
browser.Navigate("https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/liquid/reg/account/create-account!input.action");
```

The *DocumentCompleted* event will fire several times, sometimes before the captcha has finished loading, so check for null before using it. The code for the event looks as follows:

```cs
void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
        var item = browser.Document.GetElementById("recaptcha_challenge_image");
        if (item != null)
            pictureBox1.Load(item.GetAttribute("src"));
    }
```

Comment: The picturebox just remains the same ?

Comment: You need to make sure the pictureBox is appropriately sized, is that what you mean?

Comment: No nothing shows in the pictureBox, & image is sent "Zoom" so the image fits no matter the size but no image is even showing.

Comment: Then try setting the size manually and see if it works. All I can say is, that the captcha displays in my case.

Comment: Can you link me the source so I can take a look at it, maybe I am missing something or maybe its my theme

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/Xpm8EuTx - Just copy and paste it in your form designer with form name "Form1"

Comment: Now I get this https://gyazo.com/c4ce05e40a2723d41a690e2a867e0944 and it completely destroyed my theme

Comment: Okay, I'm not going to write your whole software for you, and the error you got is pretty obvious. Try figuring it out yourself.

Comment: I am not asking you to write my whole code I am asking how to set captcha to show in a picture box & the code you gave just gives me errors, I have only been coding for a few months and everything I do is self taught, this site is where users like me get help, saying "Try figuring it out yourself." is in no way helpful.

Comment: And I answered that question. Also, the code doesn't give you errors if you assemble it correctly. The exception that you get can be resolved by applying basic programming knowledge. So maybe read a book about the basics of C# or simply google what a NullReferenceException is.